# Softcore vs hardcore for power consumption

Tags: power, softcore

What is the difference between soft core and hard macro processors used in FPGAs in terms of power?

Comment: Welcome to the site. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your work and findings so far in considerable detail. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Hard should always have better performance per watt.

If all other things are equal (and they never are), the hard core will be both faster and lower power than a soft core by a significant margin.

Answer (score 0):

It’s hard to say exactly. At the same clock rate, the soft IP version will use more power as it uses more die area and resources. But the hard macro can and likely will be run faster, so its power will increase.

If you have access to the FPGA place-and-route tool, one of the reports it should give you is power. Try it both ways and see.